# awk variable assignment statement explanation needed

Tags: awk, gawk

ok, straight to the point, here is the codes, I formatted the codes a little to make it easy to read:

```
awk '{
t=$0   ; 
$0=t   ; $0=//           ; print "$0=//           ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/./          ; print "$0=/./          ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/*/          ; print "$0=/*/          ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/**/         ; print "$0=/**/         ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/[0-9]/      ; print "$0=/[0-9]/      ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/[a-z]/      ; print "$0=/[a-z]/      ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/[0-9][a-z]/ ; print "$0=/[0-9][a-z]/ ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/5/          ; print "$0=/5/          ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/55/         ; print "$0=/55/         ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/x/          ; print "$0=/x/          ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/5x/         ; print "$0=/5x/         ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/x5/         ; print "$0=/x5/         ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/xoo/        ; print "$0=/xoo/        ; value of $0 is ",$0
$0=t   ; $0=/500/        ; print "$0=/500/        ; value of $0 is ",$0
}'<<<"5x"
```

I got this output:

```
$0=//           ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/./          ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/*/          ; value of $0 is  0
$0=/**/         ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/[0-9]/      ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/[a-z]/      ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/[0-9][a-z]/ ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/5/          ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/55/         ; value of $0 is  0
$0=/x/          ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/5x/         ; value of $0 is  1
$0=/x5/         ; value of $0 is  0
$0=/xoo/        ; value of $0 is  0
$0=/500/        ; value of $0 is  0
```

I cannot understand why I got this output. I thought awk would complain about the assignment statement, but it didn't... It seems that awk is doing weird regex matching check when I did `$0=/xxx/`? that is, `$0=/pattern/` is same as `$0=$0~/pattern/`?

then I did this test:

```
kent$  echo "xx"|awk '{y="777";y=/x/;print y}'                                                                                                                              
1

kent$  echo "xx"|awk '{y="777";y=/7/;print y}'                                                                                                                              
0
```

so it seems, `foo=/pattern/` is same as `foo=$0~/pattern/`

but I am not sure... cannot find the info in document/man page.

I found it when I was answering an awk question here @ SO.

I tested with my awk:

```
kent$  awk --version|head -1
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 5.1.2)
```

I appreciate if someone could explain me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

after doing more tests, it turns out (again, not sure, since I didn't find it in document), **within** `{...}`, the `/pattern/` alone is short form of `$0~/pattern/` same as outside the `{...}`, like `/patter/{do something}` . so we could do:

```
kent$  echo "xx"|awk '{if(/x/)print "ok"}'                                                                                                                                  
ok
```

I don't know if it is a standard feature of awk script syntax. and if it works for all awk implementation. I am still searching manual and man page...

Comment: That's a good puzzle, and I can't see the answer right now, but I wasn't surprised that `$0=//` and all the others passed. Isn't that the same as when you make a mistake in `c` like `while(i=j){j=func(...); .. }`, when really intending `while(i==j) { ... }`. D (I know, not a great example). Does using different input, or just as END block with `/dev/null` change anything? I assume that if you nave an initial `print "#dbg:$0="$0`, you see the correct value there? Good luck!

Comment: BSD awk is the same except for `/*/` and `/**/`, which are syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/regexp/` is just shorthand for `$0 ~ /regexp/`

`var = ($0 ~ /regexp/)` assigns var the result of the comparison, 1 for true, zero otherwise.

`$0 = ($0 ~ /regexp/)` assigns $0 the result of the comparison of $0 and /regexp/

`$0 = ($0 ~ //)` assigns $0 the result of looking for an empty string in $0, which there always is, so the condition is true so the result is 1

`$0 = //` does the same

`$0 = /*/` is looking for a literal `*` in $0, which there isn't so the result is zero.

`$0 = /**/` is looking for a literal `*` repeated ZERO or more times in $0, which there are zero of them so that result is 1.

No mystery, nothing weird...

Comment: thx Ed, I added an EDIT in my question.  but this form I have never used/seen before: `'{if(/pat/){dostuff}}'`  does it work for all awk impl. ?

Comment: My book about 'awk' says the same: `/pat/` is shorthand for `$0~/pat/` and `if ($0~/pat/)` is the same as `if (/pat/)`.

Comment: thx Ed. +1! and this is funny: `echo "20"|awk '{a=5(/10/);print a}'` will output `50`

Comment: @Kent : how is it funny ? that's compliant with how `posix` defined `awk` - a string concat of `5` with the failed pattern (False `0`). `5( )` wouldn't ever be misinterpreted as a function call since no function or variable can start its name with a digit. Some might believe a true boolean type should exist, and that should print out `5False`, which I find even uglier. With a `0/1` integer output for booleans, it makes it ultra easy to perform arithmetic on them instead of having to do an extra type re-casting like in `python`

Answer (score 2):

There is not mystery here you are just setting the value of `$0` to the value of the evaluated regular expression match. The right hand side is evaluated first, if the line matches the regular expression match the results is True *i.e. 1*, else the results is False *i.e. 0*.

Comment: Given that `/*/` is 0, I assume that it's interpreting `/**/` as `/\**/`.

Comment: `/**/` is zero or more occurrences of the character `*`. There are zero of them in his input so the condition `$0 ~ /**/` is true.

Comment: @Kevin. Correct. An RE repetitions metacharacter like `*`, `+`, or `?` is simply that literal character when it's the first one in an RE.

Comment: @EdMorton BSD awk doesn't behave that way. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @sudo_O thx for the answer. from the output, yes it works like that, I wrote it in my question too. I knew `/pat/{do stuff}', but I don't find (so far) any documentation, that is saying `{if(/pat/)...}` is same as `{if($0~/pat/)..}`

Comment: @Kevin In the GNU awk manual it says `In POSIX awk and gawk, the ‘*’, ‘+’, and ‘?’ operators stand for themselves when there is nothing in the regexp that precedes them. For example, /+/ matches a literal plus sign. However, many other versions of awk treat such a usage as a syntax error. `

Comment: You edited your question many time since my answer, yes that is how it behaves, you said it, I said, Ed said it, if you can't find it in the doc then it's not in the doc. Why do you think `awk` would evaluate an expression differently inside and outside of a block?

Comment: @sudo_O first +1 for your answer. `{x=y}` is assigning y to x, `y{..}` if y is true, do stuff. so same expression (y here), in/outside `{..}` could be different. I thought `{x=/pat/}` awk would throw exception, because `/pat/` is not a string/number. but I was wrong. thx. I edited my answer without refreshing the page, so didn't see any answers, sorry.

Comment: `/pat/` is a regular expression match whose result **is** a number though `0,1`. The regex match is evaluated **first**, just like `$0=substr($0,1,5)` where the function is evaluated first and the resulting substring is assigned.

Comment: @Kent : to elaborate on `Chris Seymour`'s point, a stranger way to express `logical AND &&` would be to directly multiply the 2 boolean conditions, like `/FN/ * (3^$7 == 2187)`