# How to pass a regular expression to a function in AWK

Tags: awk

I do not know how to pass an regular expression as an argument to a function.

If I pass a string, it is OK,

I have the following awk file,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function find(name){
    for(i=0;i<NF;i++)if($(i+1)~name)print $(i+1)
}

{
    find("mysql")
}
```

I do something like

```
$ ./fct.awk <(echo "$str")
```

This works OK.

But when I call in the awk file,

```
{
    find(/mysql/)
}
```

This does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot (should not) pass regex constant to a user-defined function. you have to use dynamic regex in this case. like `find("mysql")`

if you do `find(/mysql/)`, what does awk do is : `find($0~/mysql/)` so it pass a `0` or `1` to your `find(..)` function.

see this question for detail.

[awk variable assignment statement explanation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795408/awk-variable-assignment-statement-explanation-needed)

also
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps

section: 6.1.2 Using Regular Expression Constants

Comment: Nice explanation on what goes wrong, but it would be nice with a solution as well. Passing a string will have trouble to deal with things like "\w+". So this is not really a generic solution in this case.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Using regex in functions is allowed with GNU awk v4.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372957/2214695

Answer (score 4):

```
warning: regexp constant for parameter #1 yields boolean value
```

The regex gets evaluated (matching against `$0`) before it's passed to the function. You have to use strings.

Note: make sure you do proper escaping: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU awk, you *can* use regular expression as user defined function parameter.
You have to define your regex as `@/.../`.

In your example, you would use it like this:

```
function find(regex){
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if($i ~ regex)
                    print $i
}

{
    find(@/mysql/)
}
```

It's called [strongly type regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strong-Regexp-Constants.html) and it's available since [GNU awk version 4.2](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2017-10/msg00004.html) (Oct 2017).

Example [here](https://ideone.com/VcbTBb).

Answer (score 0):

use quotations, treat them as a string. this way it works for mawk, mawk2, and gnu-gawk. but you'll also need to double the backslashes since making them strings will eat away one of them right off the bat.

in your examplem just `find("mysql")` will suffice.

you can actually get it to pass arbitrary regex as you wish, and not be confined to just gnu-gawk, as long as you're willing to make them strings not the `@/../` syntax others have mentioned. This is where the # of backslashes make a difference.

You can even make regex out of arbitrary bytes too, preferably via octal codes. if you do `"\342\234\234"` as a regex, the system will convert that into actual bytes in the regex before matching.

While there's nothing with that approach, if you wanna be 100% safe and prefer not having arbitrary bytes flying around , write it as

```
"[\\342][\\234][\\234]"  ----> ✜
```

Once initially read by awk to create an internal representation, it'll look like this :

```
[\342][\234][\234]
```

which will still match the identical objects you desire (in this case, some sort of cross-looking dingbat). This will spit out annoying warnings in unicode-aware mode of gawk due to attempting to enclose non-ASCII bytes directly into square brackets. For that use case,

```
"\\342\\234\\234" ------(eqv to )--->  /\342\234\234/
```

will keep gawk happy and quiet. Lately I've been filling the gaps in my own codes and write regex that can mimic all the Unicode-script classes that perl enjoys.